# How to start Visual Studio Code in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, visual-studio-code

I downloaded Visual Studio Code and also extracted. I could not run the code file. I got error of:

> Can not run binary file.

How to run a Visual Studio code in Ubuntu?

Comment: Your computer is amd64?

Comment: Resolved. There was problem of operating system. It can not allow to execute binary file.